# String library isnt importing getline function

Tags: c++, string, string.h

Im using string library but I can't seem to use the get line function
used both string and string.h but its still not working
I've added the code below and it basically is just to use input numbers in a text file and then using them in a sorting mehthod

**the problem is that im only getting the error mentioned below and can't seem to wrap my head around the solution to it**

```
,,assignmentDTS.cpp:34:17: error: no matching function for call to 'getline'
                getline(inputFile,tempnumstring);
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
```

```
class sorting {  
    public:
    void bubblesort(int arraySize){
        int num;
        int *arr=new int[arraySize];
        ofstream inputFile("data.txt");
        if(inputFile.is_open()){
            for (int i = 0; i <arraySize; i++){
                string tempnumstring;
                std::getline(inputFile,tempnumstring);
                num=stoi(tempnumstring);
                arr[i]=num;
            }
```

Comment: I think you want <string> not <string.h>. The latter is a C header, not C++.

Comment: I did it and its still not working

Comment: Did you remember the std:: in front to specify the namespace ??

Comment: If it is still not working you need to edit your question to have the bit of code where you include the header and where you use the function.  I figure you are including the header and then not using `std::getline` (including the namespace) https://onlinegdb.com/t4I0Lf67P7 or you don't have a `using` declaration to avoid needing the namespace https://onlinegdb.com/VGPQi9aCr

Comment: I've done that swell and I've added the code for understanding

Comment: My compiler spits out *no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ofstream&, std::string&)'* Note the `std::ofstream`. Looks like you're trying to read from a file headed in the other direction.

Comment: And there we go: `ofstream inputFile("data.txt");` needs to be  `ifstream inputFile("data.txt");` The `fstream` starts with `i` for input stream, rather than `o` for output stream.

Comment: Side note: `int *arr=new int[arraySize];` looks like it's leaked. This could be a good place to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). `std::vector arr(arraySize);`.

Comment: Side note: Making a [mre] to go in the question often reduces the noise around the mistake enough for you to be able to spot the mistake yourself before asking the question.

Comment: sorry im new to this

Comment: No worries. Looks like it's just a silly typo swapping an o for an i, and we've all done that. Better that than an i for an i, I guess.

Comment: OP I want to save you a world of hurt years down the line: don't use `using namespace std;`

Comment: Your bubblesort function has no business doing _any_ I/O. Get input in `main()`, _then_ call bubblesort to sort it, then pring it out.

Comment: I know it doesn't but its the requirement of the assignment

Comment: Again no worries. Give the teacher what they want, but when you escape into the real world know that when you have little tiny functions with the minimum possible responsibility the functions are easier to test and bugs and mistakes are easier to isolate and debug. The stupider you can be when writing a program, the better.

Answer (score 2):

And there we go: `ofstream inputFile("data.txt");` needs to be `ifstream inputFile("data.txt");` The `fstream` starts with `i` for input stream, rather than `o` for output stream.

Answered on chat

Answer (score 1):

**std::getline** is declared in `#include <string>` per the [C++ Library Standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline%23Example).

The `#include <string.h>` statement includes the [C Library Standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring) string library which has no **getline** function. This header contains functions like **memcpy** and **strcpy**.

> The C++ recommended way to reference the C "string.h" header is `#include <cstring>`.

Comment: I did that aswell but its still not worrking

Comment: @SabeerFaisal did you use just `getline` or `std::getline`?

Comment: I've tried both

Comment: @SabeerFaisal You have two mistakes: One the missing <string> header and the other the swap of `ofstream` for `ifstream`. Both produce similar initial error messages in Visual Studio.